# How to Let Spark Handle Bigger Data Sets?

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a very complex query that needs to join 9 or more tables with some 'group by' expressions . Most of these tables have almost the same of numbers of the rows. These tables also have some columns that can be used as the 'key' to partition the tables.

Previously, the app ran fine, but now the data set has 3~4 times data as before. My tests turned out if the row count of each table is less than 4,000,000, the application can still run pretty nicely. However, if the count is more than that, the application writes hundreds of terabytes of shuffling and the application stalls (no matter how I adjust the memory, partition, executors, etc.). The actual data probably is just dozens of Gs.

I would think that if the partitioning works properly, Spark shouldn't do shuffle so much and the join should be done on each node. It is puzzling that why Spark is not so 'smart' to do so.

I could split the data set (with the 'key' I mentioned above) into many data sets that these data sets can be dealt with independently. But the burden will be on myself...it discounts the very reason to use Spark.  What other approaches that could help?

I use Spark 2.0 over Hadoop YARN.

Comment: How did you adjust partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My tests turned out if the row count of each table is less than 4,000,000, the application can still run pretty nicely. However, if the count is more than that, the application writes hundreds of terabytes of shuffling

When joining datasets if the size of one side is less than a certain configurable size, spark broadcasts the entire table to each executor so that join may be performed locally everywhere. Your above observation is consistent with this. You can also provide broadcast hint explicitly to the spark, like so `df1.join(broadcast(df2))`

Other than that, can you please provide more specifics about your problem?

[Sometime ago I was also grappling with the issue of join and shuffles for one of our jobs that had to handle couple of TBs. We were using RDDs (and not the dataset api). I wrote about my findings [here][1](https://blog.imaginea.com/investigations-into-spark-rdd-join/). These may be of some use to you are try to reason about the underlying data shuffle.]

**Update**: According to [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) -- `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is the configurable property key. `10 MB` is its default value. And it does the following:

> Configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join. By setting this value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled. Note that currently statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the command ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan has been run.

So apparently, this is supported only for the Hive tables.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I looked at DAG and confirmed your understanding.  My current implementation is using sql, registering all DataFrames (Dataset in Spark 2.0) as tables and I don't know how to broadcast the tables.  I did experiment broadcasting the DataFrames first, and them register them as tables. Sometimes it looks it does broadcast and sometimes it does not. But even it 'broadcasts', the program will still get stuck at some point.

Comment: You mentioned "if the size of one side is less than a certain configurable size". What is the parameter? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the my answer, to include the relevant bit from Spark Sql documentation. (I believe my original answer is missing the point. There's perhaps more to it that needs to be reproduced.) Can you provide more details on what kind of data you have, where you're loading it from. I would like to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue we had partially also due to the programming error by one of our team. Your explanation indeed help me understand how the things work for this piece.